# How can I update multiple tables on a single form in ms access?

Tags: forms, ms-access

I have 3 tables. I have one form as main which has respective fields from the
3 tables. I want to save new records entered by clicking on save button.

Comment: Could you please post your existing code?

Comment: This is what form/subform arrangement is for. Otherwise, you need unbound form and lots of VBA.